# How to implement unique pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

Thanks to some useful and informative comments on my previous code. Now I start to work on how to implement unique pointers in my code. I would like to ask if I used the unique pointers correctly. Also, I would like to know if my code would be efficient if I used unique pointers that way. So far I only observed that the unique pointers are destructed automatically once it is out of scope. what are some other variations when unique pointers are used. I need some further explanation on how to use unique pointers in the context of the creation of my own vector class. Part of my code is as following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>
template<typename S>
class MyVector{
private:
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
    std::unique_ptr<S[]>a;
    void allocate(){
        capacity = size*2;
        auto temp = std::make_unique<S[]>(capacity);
        for(size_t i=0; i<this->getSize();++i){
            temp[i]=std::move(a[i]);
        }
    }

public:
    MyVector():size(0), capacity(1), a(new S[1]){};
    size_t getSize(){return size;}
    size_t getCapacity(){return capacity;}
    void pushBack(S input){
        ++size;
        if(this->getSize()==this->getCapacity()){
            this->allocate();
        }
        a[this->getSize()-1]=input;
    }
    S &operator[](size_t p){return a[p];}
```

Comment: Before I change the title I'd like to confirm: You are looking for assistance on the use of `std::unique_ptr`, and not assistance on making your own version of `std::unique_ptr`, correct?

Comment: Your `allocate()` private member function should presumably be more aptly called `grow()`, or similar, and it should contain the additional statement `a=std::move(temp);` at the end.

Comment: @user4581301 Inspecting the code example it seems OP want's just to use `std::unique_ptr` instead of their own implementation. Looks more that a simple standard container like `std::vector` should be used. I don't see any advantage building your own, hand rolled vector class.

Comment: Prefer `a(make_unique<S[]>(1))` to `a(new S[1])`. It provides extra safety guarantees. Documentation for `make_unique`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Comment: @user9212993 this is my thinking as well. I'm 90% certain, but not certain enough to potentially deface the question.

Comment: I think your usage of `std::unique_ptr<>` is okay, but there are other issues with your code: usage of `this->getSize()` instead of simply `size` from within member functions, a non-empty `MyVector` when using the default constructor.

Comment: Unrelated: consider making the default capacity in the default constructor something more useful like 10. This staves of the very likely possibility of many resizes in the first few `pushBack`s.

Comment: @user4581301 correct. I would like to see what would be the difference between using unique pointers and normal pointers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Assuming that the code works correctly, you might want to write up your samples in a more-complete fashion and ask for critique over at [codereview.se]. Be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there!

Comment: @Toby Speight Thank you very much for that. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were numerous issues with your code. Below, I addressed all I found in an improved code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<memory>

template<typename S>
class MyVector
{
    size_t m_size = 0;           // use `size` as name for public member
    size_t m_capacity = 0;       // give default value
    std::unique_ptr<S[]> m_data;
    void grow_capacity()
    {
        m_capacity += m_capacity? m_capacity : 1;
        auto temp = std::make_unique<S[]>(m_capacity);
        for(size_t i=0; i!=m_size; ++i)
            temp[i] = std::move(m_data[i]);
        m_data = std::move(temp);      // 
    }
public:
    MyVector() = default;         // let compiler work this out
    size_t size() const noexcept  // const member
    { return m_size; }
    size_t capacity() const noexcept
    { return m_capacity; }
    void pushBack(S const&input)
    {
        if(m_size == m_capacity)   // only grow when needed
            grow_capacity();
        m_data[m_size++] = input;
    }
    void pushBack(S &&input)       // version for moving in
    {
        if(m_size == m_capacity)
            grow_capacity();
        m_data[m_size++] = std::move(input);
    }
    S &operator[](size_t p)
    { return m_data[p]; }
    S const &operator[](size_t p) const  // const data access
    { return m_data[p]; }
};
```

Comment: why do you use the ternary operator ? does it work as increment the m_capacity by one ? if m_capacity is not zero?

Comment: Yes. Usually I simply double `m_capacity`, which is most simply done as `m_capacity += m_capacity;`, but because I start at `m_capacity=0`, I must instead set it to `1` when it was `0`. This can be done by adding `1` in this case.

Comment: based on the improved grow_capacity() and the pushBack function that you created above, would a for-loop inside an insert() function under the class be necessary ?

Comment: @w1583236 can you specify what your insert function is supposed to do?

Comment: the insertion function will pass two parameters: the first is the index indicating which position to insert; the second is the actual data to be inserted.

Comment: @w1583236 Since the data are stored in a contiguous array, the `insert()` will need to move all existing elements after the inserted one by one position. This cannot be avoided. Therefore, insertion is typically not a good idea for contiguous data.